# PostgreSQL unstable order messing up SQL injection

Tags: postgresql, sql-injection

I have a PostgreSQL database named `sqli`, with two tables, defined as:

```
create table articles(id int, content text);
create table users(username varchar(32), password varchar(32));
```

I am working on a library for performing SQL injection, a usecase the library should support is:

- Not performing aggregation (`string_agg`)
- retrieving a maximum of N characters per query

The reason aggregation shouldn't be used is that `string_agg` only works on `PostgreSQL 9.0` and higher (and some users might need to use the library on older versions).

The reason for the second constraint is that some applications might truncate the output of the SQL query before returning the result to the user, for example, consider a case where you get only the first 3 characters of the query result.

If the output length is set to 3, my library would run the following queries to get the names of the tables:

```
(select count(1)::text from information_schema.tables where table_schema='public')
=> 2, expect two rows
(select substr(coalesce(table_name::text,'')::text,1,3) from information_schema.tables where table_schema='public' limit 1 offset 0)
=> returns "use"
(select substr(coalesce(table_name::text,'')::text,4,3) from information_schema.tables where table_schema='public' limit 1 offset 0)
=> returns "rs", length < 3, move to next row
(select substr(coalesce(table_name::text,'')::text,1,3) from information_schema.tables where table_schema='public' limit 1 offset 1)
=> returns "art"
(select substr(coalesce(table_name::text,'')::text,4,3) from information_schema.tables where table_schema='public' limit 1 offset 1)
=> returns "icl"
(select substr(coalesce(table_name::text,'')::text,7,3) from information_schema.tables where table_schema='public' limit 1 offset 1)
=> returns "es", length < 3, stop
```

Result: `users` and `articles`.

What I don't understand is the following:
While trying to retrieve the column names using the same algorithm, here are the results:

```
(select count(1)::text from information_schema.columns where table_name='users' and table_schema='public')
=> 2
(select substr(coalesce(column_name::text,'')::text,1,3) from information_schema.columns where table_name='users' and table_schema='public' limit 1 offset 0)
=> "pas"
(select substr(coalesce(column_name::text,'')::text,4,3) from information_schema.columns where table_name='users' and table_schema='public' limit 1 offset 0)
=> "swo"
(select substr(coalesce(column_name::text,'')::text,7,3) from information_schema.columns where table_name='users' and table_schema='public' limit 1 offset 0)
=> "me" !! THIS IS WRONG
(select substr(coalesce(column_name::text,'')::text,1,3) from information_schema.columns where table_name='users' and table_schema='public' limit 1 offset 1)
=> "use"
(select substr(coalesce(column_name::text,'')::text,4,3) from information_schema.columns where table_name='users' and table_schema='public' limit 1 offset 1)
=> "rna"
(select substr(coalesce(column_name::text,'')::text,7,3) from information_schema.columns where table_name='users' and table_schema='public' limit 1 offset 1)
=> "rd" !! THIS IS ALSO WRONG
```

The result is `passwome` and `usernard`. the `me` is from `username`, and `rd` from `password`.

I know there is no guaranteed order stability without using an `ORDER BY` clause with a column having unique values, but I don't know the database schema in advance, and this algorithm works on any other database management system I've tested, any idea why it's not working? Or any suggestion on how to get correct results?

Comment: You **are** getting a "correct" result. As you said for yourself: there is no guaranteed order unless you use an `order by`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the answer, any way to `order by` when you don't know a column that has unique values that can be used for this purpose? (or any algorithm that can be used to detect such errors and correct them?). Very often, the users don't even know the database schema when they start running queries.

Comment: Obviously `order by column_name` as the name must be unique per table

Answer (score 1):

As you said, result row ordering is not guaranteed without `ORDER BY`. Comparison with other database systems are pointless, because each implements query execution and storage internals differently.

Bot yours is a non-problem: `information_schema.columns` has a column `ordinal_position` for the express purpose of determining the column ordering. You should use that.